# How can I write a simple CGAL code to mesh a 2d rectangle?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal, triangulation

I need to use CGAL to generate a mesh within a finite element code. I looked at the documentation and I found it a bit difficult to understand, especially given the fact that I am not an expert with programming in C. Therefore I would like to ask you if you can provide or link a simple code to mesh a rectangle and to somehow export the mesh (i.e. matrixes containing nodes and element information) to a file or to reuse it within my code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_2mesh_global_8cpp-example.html). You can use [this function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__Delaunay__triangulation__2.html#acc9e0ac49922f90f7418548a40f6a6c3) to insert a polygon directly. If you need to mesh a domain with holes, you'll need to use seeds like in [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_2mesh_with_seeds_8cpp-example.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I indeed looked at that example on the documentation but I could not understand how to extract the mesh information (nodes and elements) from the cdt structure. Can you please provide some more details?

Comment: The post from enni707 gives you a useful pointer. If you want an already written function you can use the function [`write_vtu`](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/Mesh_2/group__PkgMesh2IO.html#ga24b8e1265bbe823f443c1b7d544f40e0) that will be available in CGAL 4.14 and that is already provided in the master branch. You can also look at the implementation if you want to have an alternative output.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this one](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/How-to-extract-faces-from-a-CDT-examples-Mesh-2-mesh-global-cpp-td953556.html) useful. It shows you how to print out vertex and elements.